# parsing method and special cases

Tags: java

I have an HTML removal method mostly working. However, there is a small problem in some special cases. The problem occurs with input strings like this:

> Abraham`<blah>`Adam Savage: I reject your reality, and substitute my
>       own.

The code will remove the `<blah>` tag just fine, but combines the two strings before and after it which creates "AbrahamAdam". I need "Abrah" and "Adam" to be separated.

Any ideas?

Comment: if (flagForHTML=false) if condition is always false so your  new = new + readIn.charAt(i); will never get execute

Comment: Can't you add a space when you remove something?

Comment: @Thusitha Thillina Dayaratne: I'm not actually removing, I'm just not reading the ones that are flagged.

Comment: then you read it as a space.

Comment: @Thusitha Thillina Dayaratne: I tried that, but it made the token before "<blah>" a space too.

Comment: @RadScorpius Did you try JSOUP library?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public static String removeHTML(String justScanned) { 
    String newStr = "";
    int length = readIn.length();  
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (readIn.charAt(i) == '<') {
            flagForHTML = true;
            newStr += " ";
        }
        if (readIn.charAt(i) == '>') {
            flagForHTML = false;
            newStr += " ";
        } else {
            if (!flagForHTML) {
                newStr += readIn.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. StringBuilder was used because it is more efficient than using String when it comes to building strings.

```
public static String removeHTML(String justScanned) { 
    StringBuilder new = new StringBuilder();
    boolean insideTag = false;
    for(int i =0; i < justScanned.length(); i++) {
       char currentChar = justScanned.charAt(i);
       if(currentChar == '<') {
           insideTag = true;
       } else if(currentChar == '>') {
           insideTag = false;
       } else {
           if(! insideTag) {
               new.append(currentChar);
           }
       }
    }
    return new.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", " ")
```